# FactoryGirl, 2 times creates user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

I really dont understand of making assotiations. In spec_helper I have got

```
def log_in_user
  user = User.find_by_name 'User1'
  user = FactoryGirl.create :user1 unless user
  sign_in user
end
```

in rspec

```
let(:product) { FactoryGirl.build :product_A }


describe "GET confirm purchase" do
    it "xxx" do
      log_in_user

      Product.should_receive(:find_active_by_id).with("1").and_return(product)

       ...
   end
end
```

factories.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :user do
        encrypted_password 'abcdef1'
        confirmed_at Time.now

            factory :user1 do
              email 'user1@test.com'
              name 'User1'
              year 1984
            end
    end

    factory :product do
        factory :product_A do
          name "product A"
          association :user, factory: :user1
        end
    end
end
```

when I run test case an exception occures: 
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Email has already been taken

It looks like user1 is creating 2 times, one in log_in_user and the second one in factory:  association :user, factory: :user1

I am right? If yes, how can I solve this? I want to create user and have assotiation defined in factory product

best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you factory `:product_A` it is automatically calling the factory for `:user1`.

Then you factory `:user1` again in the `log_in_user`, but the validation on unique emails is preventing the second `:user1` from being created.

I would recommend you make email a `sequence` like so:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  sequence :email do |n|
    "user#{n}@test.com"
  end

  factory :user do
    encrypted_password 'abcdef1'
    confirmed_at Time.now

    factory :user1 do
      email
      name 'User1'
      year 1984
    end
  end

  factory :product do
    factory :product_A do
      name "product A"
      association :user, factory: :user1
    end
  end

end
```

Then, I would alter the `sign_in_user` to take an (optional) user as an option like this:

```
def log_in_user(user)
  user =|| User.find_by_name 'User1'
  user =|| FactoryGirl.create :user1
  sign_in user
end
```

And modify your test case to pass that user object to the login:

```
let(:product) { FactoryGirl.build :product_A }

describe "GET confirm purchase" do
  it "xxx" do
    log_in_user(product.user)
    Product.should_receive(:find_active_by_id).with("1").and_return(product)
 end
end
```

Comment: Wouldn't this still create two users, which I think was his initial problem?

Comment: @RyanBigg I read the problem is that he didn't understand why it was attempting to create two users. I expanded with how I probably would proceed.